# CSS Image position not what i wanted

Tags: css

im trying to put my image on the middle top off my box. I'm sorry if this is a stupid question but I'm new to coding and I'm young. I searched on the code, everything's fine except this part. It makes my image is on like the middle mid, a bit on the left which is not what I want. Thanks

```
.profile img
{
    position: absolute!important;
    left:calc(50% - 60%px)!important;
    border: 10px solid #fff!important;
}
```

[this is what it gives me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BweRg.png)

Comment: Somewhere it says to add "top: -60px; but it makes my image disapear instead

Comment: If the image disappear, make sure you set the z-index property to a value above the container. I suppose you have given the container a position:relative setting.

Comment: Why are you using absolute positioning? Is flexbox or grid not an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will also help;

```
.profile{
  position:relative; /* set whatever height and width to this div */
}

.profile img{
    position: absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    border: 10px solid #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Flexbox containers. Using [justify-content](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_flexbox_justify-content_center) and [align-items](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_flexbox_align-items_flex-start), you should be able to put your image at the top center of your div without using absolutes. The W3 links show examples of both properties--combine them and you should achieve your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

1. Using margin:auto (by making img tag as display:block)

```css
div {background: yellow; height: 400px;}
img {border-radius:50%; margin:auto;display:block;}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
</div>
```

2. Using Flexbox

```css
div {background: yellow; height: 400px; display: flex; justify-content:center;}
img {height: 100px; border-radius: 50%;}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
</div>
```